# Protractor infinite loop

Tags: javascript, angularjs, recursion, protractor, infinite-loop

In previous question I have problem with clicking button until it will be disabled answer was:

```
var nextPage = function () {
    if (element(by.css('[ng-click="vm.nextPage()"]')).isEnabled()) {
        element(by.css('[ng-click="vm.nextPage()"]')).click();
        nextPage(); // next page
    }
    else {
        return; // the element is not enabled, last page
    }
}
```

I had to change it a little so my code looks now like this

```
 var nextPage = function() {
  if (element(by.id('next')).isEnabled()) {
    element(by.id('next')).click().then(function() {
      browser.sleep(1000);
      nextPage(); // next page
      return;
    });
  } else {
    return; // the element is not enabled, last page
  }
  return;
}
```

but now it jumps into infinite recursive calls so next step cant be performed, how couldn't I change it, without  using `.then` function does not work at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the *recursion base case is never met* and it never exists the recursion.

Remember that *everything in protractor is a promise*, **`isEnabled()` in your case is an unresolved promise which is always "truthy"**. This is why you always go to the next loop regardless of the real `isEnabled` value and eventually get the maximum recursion depth error.

Resolve the promise explicitly to get the real `isEnabled` boolean value:

```
element(by.id('next')).isEnabled().then(function (isEnabled) {
    if (isEnabled) {
        // ...
    } else {
        return; // the element is not enabled, last page
    }
});
```

---

As a side note, *shameless promotion* that could have helped catch this issue earlier - the [`eslint-plugin-protractor`](https://github.com/alecxe/eslint-plugin-protractor) and [it's rule to catch when protractor promises are used inside `if` conditions directly without being explicitly resolved](https://github.com/alecxe/eslint-plugin-protractor/blob/master/docs/rules/no-promise-in-if.md). Here is what it would output if executed against a code like posted in the question:

```
$ eslint test.js
/path/to/test.js
  2:5   warning  Unexpected "isEnabled()" inside if condition  protractor/no-promise-in-if 
  4:13  warning  Unexpected browser.sleep()                    protractor/no-browser-sleep
```